# Multiple booleans if condition in C#

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

In plain language - if this portion of the script detects that the direction is "right" and the two booleans "Wallright" and "WallsLeftOrRight" are false then play the standard walking animation and move the sprite...

This portion works okay, it is the next portion I am having trouble with.

In my mind the logic sounds workable - IF the direction is right and either of the booleans are true than play the idle animation.

In practice the game is requiring BOTH booleans to be true meaning that the | operator is requiring them both to be true. I've tried switching to the logical || operator since | appears to not be for conditions of this nature but that did nothing.  I also tried removing the two OR values from within their own bracket encapsulation but that did not work either.

```
    if ((direction == "right") && ((WallRight == false) | (WallsLeftOrRight == false)))
    {
        var newanim = character.GetComponent<Animator>();
        newanim.Play("right_walking");
        character.transform.position += Vector3.right * 0.6f * Time.deltaTime;
        charDirection = PlayerFacing.Right;
    }
    else if ((direction == "right") && ((WallRight == true) | (WallsLeftOrRight == true)))
    {
        var newanim = character.GetComponent<Animator>();
        newanim.Play("right_idle");
        charDirection = PlayerFacing.Right;
    }
```

Comment: if(direction == "right" && !(WallRight && WallsLeftOrRight)){//first condition} else if (direction == "right" && WallRight && WallsLeftOrRight){//second condition}

Comment: `(WallRight == true) | (WallsLeftOrRight == true)` - don't do stuff like that.  Just write `(WallRight  | WallsLeftOrRight )`.  See _[Make a big deal out of == true?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true/12818)_

Comment: @kashi_rock `if(direction == "right" && !(WallRight && WallsLeftOrRight)){` is exactly what is written in the first line of sample - so can you comment on your comment?

Comment: @Alexei, true but I meant that he is not using the correct way to use boolean variables

Comment: Maybe you could think of an enum. First would be direction == right && Nothing, second would be direction == right && Both. This would depends on how you set the value but it would also make it clearer.

Comment: Instead of using single pipe (|) for Or condition, Use double pipe (||)

Comment: Actually using flag enum the single pipe would make sense (just pushing my enum solution :)).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, simplify your code.

`if(WallRight == false)` is the-same as `if(!WallRight)`

`if(WallRight == true)` is the-same as `if(WallRight)`

To answer your question:

> If this portion of the script detects that the direction is "right"
>   and the two booleans "Wallright" and "WallsLeftOrRight" are false then
>   play the standard walking animation

```
if (direction == "right" && !WallRight && !WallsLeftOrRight)
```

> IF the direction is right and either of the booleans are true than
>   play the idle animation.

```
if ((direction == "right") && (WallRight || WallsLeftOrRight))
```

First, direction is checked, then `||` is used to check if either `WallRight` or `WallsLeftOrRight` is true. As you can see, `WallRight` and `WallsLeftOrRight` are put int the-same parenthesis. The check will be done once for them.

```
if (direction == "right" && !WallRight && !WallsLeftOrRight)
{
    var newanim = character.GetComponent<Animator>();
    newanim.Play("right_walking");
    character.transform.position += Vector3.right * 0.6f * Time.deltaTime;
    charDirection = PlayerFacing.Right;
}
else if ((direction == "right") && (WallRight || WallsLeftOrRight))
{
    var newanim = character.GetComponent<Animator>();
    newanim.Play("right_idle");
    charDirection = PlayerFacing.Right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First condition:

```
(direction == "right") && ((WallRight == false) | (WallsLeftOrRight == false))
```

Second Condition:

```
(direction == "right") && ((WallRight == true) | (WallsLeftOrRight == true))
```

In the first condition you check if either  `WallRight` or `WallsLeftOrRight` is false.
This condition can make a true result for these 3 situations:
`WallRight = false`, `WallsLeftOrRight = false`
`WallRight = false`, `WallsLeftOrRight = true`
`WallRight = true`, `WallsLeftOrRight = false`

Then the only remaining situation that would be checked in `else if` clause is:
`WallRight = true`, `WallsLeftOrRight = true`

You are using an `else if` clause for checking your second condition, so when the first condition results true, the second condition can not be checked.